# Trying to redirect user to a link after login

Tags: php, html, redirect, authentication

All I want to do is redirect a user to my homepage a couple seconds after they log in. Here's my code

```
<?php 
    include_once("config.php");
?>

<?php if( !(isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) ) { ?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Codecall Tutorials - Secured Login with php5</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <header id="head" >
                <p>Codecall tutorials User Login</p>
            <p><a href="register.php"><span id="register">Register</span></a></p>
        </header>

        <div id="main-wrapper">
            <div id="login-wrapper">
                <form method="post" action="">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="usn">Username : </label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="username" />
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <label for="passwd">Password : </label>
                            <input type="password" maxlength="30" required name="password" />
                        </li>
                        <li class="buttons">
                            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log me in" />
                            <input type="button" name="register" value="Register" onclick="location.href='register.php'" />
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>

<?php 
} else {
    $usr = new Users;
    $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

    if( $usr->userLogin() ) {

        echo "Welcome"; 


    } else {
        echo "Incorrect Username/Password"; 

    }
}
?>
```

Also, it would be very nice to have a user page created after a user registers. I have the register code all set but this is something I would like to implement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This this code snippet:

`header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' );`

Here is a reference link if you need it - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do PHP redirects:

```
 header('location:index.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

`header();` phpfunction to redirect your page into certain location you want.

```
if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
        ob_start(); // use output buffering to avoid "header already sent error"
        echo "Welcome"; //should try to remove this if you want because its unecessary now since your redirecting your page
        header('Location: pagetoredirect');
        ob_end_flush(); //now the headers are sent

    } else {
        echo "Incorrect Username/Password"; 

    }
```

Source([PHP.NET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

Comment: this will fail. You can't set `header` after any output (including `echo`)

Comment: I've tried the header approach, and it would make sense to put it in the if statement, but this still does nothing

Comment: @ariefbayu seems working fine even theres an echo statement and also in php.net there are many samples having echo statement before using header to redirect..

Comment: @ClayBanks i thinks your having problems in passing values of your post.

Comment: @Kaii: If I remembered correctly, it will work if you use output buffering.

Comment: @ariefbayu yes thats true for avoiding "headers already sent" error but this will still work.there would be still an "headers already sent" but would see because the browser follows redirect it before it would display.but just to be safe for errors lets just add output buffering to avoid it  :D

Comment: @ClayBanks can we know what your form outputs after a form submission?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to clear your html first:

1. Make your top part codes into:

   ```
   <?php 
       include_once("config.php");

       if( !(isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) ) { ?>
   ```
2. Add `header` where you want to redirect:

   ```
       if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
           header('Location: /path/to/new/page.php');
       } else {
           echo "Incorrect Username/Password"; 
       }
   ```
3. Another way is to use javascript:

   ```
       if( $usr->userLogin() ) { ?>

           <div class="message">
               Thank you for logging in. You will be redirected in few seconds.
               Click <a href="/path/to/new/page.php">here</a> if not redirected.
           </div>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               window.location = "/path/to/new/page.php";
           </script>
       <?php
       } else {
           echo "Incorrect Username/Password"; 
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can redirect your page through header() like this

```
header("location:yoursite.com?$msg=welcome user");
```

and it is important to notice that header() must be called before any actual output is seen...